# PEP-Proxy-Steelskin Log configuration

Tags: logging, proxy, rpm, fiware

I am configuring the FIWARE PEP-Proxy-steelskin without RPM, due it is installed in a Ubuntu machine.
After the installation, no log appears in /var/log/pepProxy , and I am afraid this is because of the installation.

Is there a way to create the log without RPM?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed. Steelskin does not log to a particular file, but to the standard output. That's why you are not seeing any log in /var/log. In order to get the log, just make a redirection of the standard output:

```
nohup bin/pepProxy &> /var/log/pepProxy.log
```

In this case, you would need to manage the logs using externals tools, like logrotate, the same way it is done in the RPM spec.